# Can we automatically forbid or flag posts that start with the text "N down vote favorite"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, quality-filter, se-quality-project

Yet again I see a post that has [*0 down vote favorite*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178365/292385) as the first line in the question.  This happened because the OP just copied and pasted a question that they already had and they caught the vote section when they did.  Can we either stop submission of these or at least raise an auto flag?  I have tried and I cannot think of a valid question or answer that would be harmed if they could not start with *N down vote favorite*.

Comment: The same would apply to answers. The number of plagiarised posts I've deleted that included that text at the start..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Updated the title to include answers.  Don't want to forget about those

Comment: If you'd block posting posts that start with that, users would just remove it to post their posts, which would make it harder to detect it as a copy. So auto-flag would be a better option.

Comment: [71 results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=down+vote+favorite) ... are you sure you want to spend dev time on that?

Comment: @rene: more false positives than true matches.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, an exact search only gives 8 results but that is such a sad number ...

Comment: @rene But that doesn't count the number of those that have be deleted.  My gut says the majority have been.

Comment: You don't dare to play the *deleted posts* card. You know I have no defense against that!

Comment: @NathanOliver - I see 430 matches for deleted posts containing "down vote favorite".

Comment: @br Thanks for the info.  I guess it is not as big of an issue as I thought.

Comment: Isn't this a FR?

Comment: @Braiam Maybe?  I just more wanted to discuss if we even wanted to do this.

Comment: 430 deleted posts with the exact string "down vote favorite", many of which are *answers* despite being copied from questions. Go figure.

Comment: Wouldn't it make *more* sense to automatically detect and raise a flag for large portions of copy-pasted content? It isn't the "N down vote favorite" that's the problem, it's the fact that the *rest* of the post is a copy-paste. A >95% match should raise an auto-flag.

Comment: @BoltClock Were they answers to the question they were posted on? I.e. the person copied and pasted the question into their answer in the process of answering it, maybe intending to put it in a quote block or something?

Comment: @CodyGray I remember it has been proposed to prevent plagiarization on tag wikis, but it had been shot down due false positives and expensive (not sure if those claims are valid anymore)

Comment: Surely a bunch of programmers could optimize a simple text-matching routine so that it would be fast enough. It only has to run when a post is submitted, not each time it loads, so slightly increasing the wait time doesn't seem like a big deal. You'd have to tweak the score threshold to minimize the number of false positives, but since a flag is being raised, false positives aren't really that big of a deal. Personally, I don't think those claims were very valid for tag wikis, either. But no one asked me. :-)

Comment: @rene Actually, it's [only 5](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22down+vote+favorite%22) (which further emphasizes your point).

Comment: Perhaps this may be a nice feature for one of the chatroom bots?

Comment: I can't bring myself to upvote, because you didn't start this with "0 down vote favorite".

Comment: 8.1 million results on google "0 down vote favorite"

Comment: @CodyGray Sure, but what about a bunch of web programmers?  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Only 28, actually. https://www.google.com/search?q=%220+down+vote+favorite%22#q=%220+down+vote+favorite%22&start=20

Comment: 0 down vote favorite thanks for posting this.

Comment: Easy, @Yakk. The web programmers just invent a site where they can outsource their programming problems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We *could* blacklist strings (both in titles and bodies) that match the regex:

```
down vote favorite
```

That would prevent this sort of copy-and-paste error. But it would not prevent people from noticing the problem and removing (or modifying) the offending string. Since the string seems a really strong signal of plagiarism (and carelessness), it's counterproductive to block it unless the system is overwhelmed with these contributions. As [rene demonstrated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342713/1438) that's not the case. The handful of extant posts were gone before started looking at the question.

So, yes, this is an incredibly annoying behavior. But it's also relatively rare.

---

That said, Shog9 added the blacklist while I was answering. So that's fine too. ;-)

[image: Block some copy-and-paste text.]

Comment: *'Body cannot contain ""'*?

Comment: Not wild about telling people which bits of text to remove here, @Tiny. As rene notes, this ain't gonna hit very many posts, so any value would be in discouraging lazy posters - and this seems sufficiently discouraging.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, I see

Comment: @TinyGiant: Shog's regex skills are superior to mine. The best I could do was quote the entire body which doesn't leave much room for a useful warning. (And might give away the game a bit sooner.)

Comment: I suppose the "Body cannot contain" part is hard-coded, @Shog9? Otherwise, the message would be clearer if you just omitted it altogether.

Comment: Yeah, that bit is mandatory for blacklisted terms in the body, @Cody.

Comment: How did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42123826) get through?  ([Metasmoke report for those with <10k)(https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/56595))

Comment: @NobodyNada: The regex is anchored to the start of the post. (That answer started with a `[` to make the link.)

Answer (score 44):

I'm all for quality.

Given the low number of occurrences of such posts:

- [current visible](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22down+vote+favorite%22) ( <s>8</s>    1 )
- [first revisions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/622040) (253) <sup>1</sup>
- [deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342712/can-we-stop-the-posting-of-a-question-or-answer-or-raise-an-auto-flag-when-the-p#comment440640_342712) (430)

I don't think it is helping an awful lot.

I wouldn't spend developer time right now and here implementing this.

<sup><sup><sup><sup>1. IKR that this doesn't include deleted post</sup></sup></sup></sup>

Comment: Your "first revision" SQL has `SELECT TOP 10` at the top. Any link with 10 rows in the resultset?

Comment: I left that intentionally there @Mat. You earned the waffles...

Comment: If there actually are only 10, then the deleted data is necessary - I've seen more than that just myself, and the one I saw pretty much all needed serious work (to say the least).

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get past the 2 minute timeout on SEDE, hold on ...

Comment: @Mat it is 253 ...

Comment: Much less than I expected. But I guess that's science... thanks for the analysis.

Comment: The visible ones are down to 1 closed question. Looks like the meta effect.

Comment: Maybe there could be a bot to grab these, google for the duplicates, and post CVs to the SOCVR room?

Comment: @JanDvorak  I just learned Gutenberg over in SO Botics is doing right that?

Comment: Oh, nice. I guess I should hang out more in there.

Comment: I have a 27" display in front of my eyes. I have problems in reading your last part. Are you sure you need that much `<sub>`? :D

Comment: @Christian No, needs *moar* `<sub>`

Comment: The expression I blacklisted is a bit more fuzzy than the search, so would've hit a few hundred more attempts (including attempts at copying answers, which don't include "favorite"). False-positive rate still crushingly low, so what the hell might as well.

Comment: If you're unhappy with your 27" display, I'll be happy to take it off your hands, @Christian. :-)