# Should the string 'noob' be added to the blacklist for question titles?

Tags: discussion, title, quality-filter, content-blocklist

#### Problem

There appear to be quite some not descriptive question titles that boil down to *[program language]-noob here...*, *noob-question why does y do y?* ([See for yourself.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Anoob))

The actual questions might be valid and quite some have answers to them, but the bad title always severely undercuts the question's quality.

Related: The section on "Degradation of Self or Others" in [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232/997587)

#### Proposed solution

Blacklist the string 'noob' and its variants such as 'newb', 'newbie', 'newbee', 'n00b' from appearing in a question's title.

[This kind of blacklisting has already been done with other strings.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342712/can-we-automatically-forbid-or-flag-posts-that-start-with-the-text-n-down-vote/342872#342872)

The string 'beginner' might have proper use and would need separate discussion if to be considered at all.

Comment: Newbie has 110k results, destroying noob, newb has 6k, newbee has 1k, n00b has 3k, beginner has 7k title matches: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Abeginner and 170k uses including use outside titles: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beginner (where valid uses are far more frequent, but this is a title ban question, and not a post content ban, so those are generally irrelevant)

Comment: You just create this game of whack-a-mole that people will work around. That's why you see so many posts that start "I have a porblem..."

Comment: Ideally, it'd be more than just a blacklist, and instead a "Hey! It looks like your title isn't very descriptive. Titles should briefly inform readers of the problem being solved." rather than "These words are not allowed in titles: 'help'.. See [Writing Good Titles]." when we know the majority of users will not follow a link, especially when the message before the link tells you how to do away with the error.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so

Comment: @Robert That doesn't mean the blacklist is futile; "People will work around it" isn't a good argument unless we actually end up with worse post titles overall because of it. If even _some_ people take the hint and rewrite their title into something more useful as a result, it will have accomplished its goal. That said– I fully agree that blacklisting "problem" is and always has been dumb– but "newb" never belongs in a title, full stop.

Comment: The fact that I've seen people intentionally introduce typograhical errors into their title to get around errors like "A question with that title already exists" makes me think that this'll cause people to find more "dumb" ways to spell newbie; though hopefully, it'll deter more than those that decide to be "imaginative" with their spellings.

Comment: The lack of research here is kind of hard to get over. Are we supposed to do the legwork to prove this is an issue? Your search doesn't even return posts with the word n3wb in the title, or n00b, or noob or whatever the goal was here. "There appears to be a problem" is simply not convincing. [Research is as much appreciated on meta as it is on main](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: The proposal might be obsolete very soon as it's not considering [meta-tag:staging-ground]. Few weeks ago was ran a beta and in the following days will be run another. [Help needed: a call for volunteer reviewers for the Staging Ground beta test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421718/1595451)

Comment: Keep in mind: https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs

Comment: [More variations](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#newbie).

Comment: I could back a proposal like this. If you can force people to stop and think long enough about describing the problem, odds are good they'll find the solution and not have to ask the question.

Comment: The highest score (open) question I could find with the word "noob" in the title is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66648590/1563833).  Interestingly it comes from a user with the word "noob" as part of their username.

Comment: I'm not against this as long as high-reputation users can still use it. Other words like "problem" have been banned before and [it's caused problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108815/349538) (pun intended). There are probably fewer good reasons to use "noob" than to use "problem", but it's impossible to say in advance that there will never be any valid uses of the word. Also as an editor I hate it when I can't edit old posts because the title contains a word that's now banned.

Comment: I would also ban ‘my code’, ‘this code’, ‘my program’, ‘this issue’, ‘this error’, ‘got an error’, ‘I have a problem’ and ‘hello’.

Comment: @user3840170 There are far too many legitimate uses of some of those to ban them.

Comment: Other strings have been blacklisted, but it's not so clear that those cases are "*this kind of blacklisting*".  In the cited case, the blacklisted pattern was taken to be both nonsense and diagnostic of a family of specific *technical* behaviors that was judged to lead to a high proportion of poor questions.  The present case is rather about editorial word choice.  The particular words under consideration may also be predictive of poor questions, but this feels qualitatively different to me.

Comment: I find the first link of the question misleading, there are only [954 non-closed questions with “_noob_” in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Anoob+closed%3A0). Is it really worth it? It’s more if we include variations, but still, we are talking about a few new questions with such titles per day, right? Or are there really so many where the title was fixed, and it was the only issue in the post?

Comment: @DidierL That’s 954 too many.

Comment: @pigrammer Are there? I am yet to see just *one*. And even if there is just a question of score at least three with a title containing one of these phrases, I am sure it would be better with a differently phrased title.

Comment: In my opinion you never ever have a reason to refer to one's developmental state (I.E. if you're a novice or not), whether it be your own or someone else's. The only reason people want to do that is because they want to use it as an excuse and/or a shield or you are genuinely not aware of the purpose of Stack Overflow. A question which does try to do it is almost certainly going to be a question which is not going to do well and should probably be posted on a different site altogether. So yeah, I would be in favour of blacklisting all such terms. On the main site only, of course.

Comment: @Larnu "Creative" spellings like those are generally a good tell that a question is rubbish, so even if the asker manages to circumvent the filter, reviewers can quickly tell that they should probably close said question. At best we're preventing badly-titled questions from being posted, at worst we have the same amount of work as currently... doesn't seem like a problem to me. As I've said in the past, please let's not allow perfect to be the enemy of good enough.

Comment: I don't disagree with that, @IanKemp . I'm just expressing my frustration that there is a minority of users (but common enough) out there that literally don't care an iota about the quality of their content, or the messages/warnings they get telling them that perhaps their content needs more "thought"

Comment: @Larnu I hear ya, but there practically isn't much we can do about them except for putting up more and more fences to make the extremely minimal amount of effort required to s**t in our pool too much for them to care about going through.

Comment: don't see a problem with noob at all. for one, it's slang, and stackoverflow as medium in the internet can use internet's language to express internet problems. the same as when an mmo player calls themself "tank" or "dps". and further, one of the main goals of so is to provide answeres to questions, and make these questions available to be found via search engine x. and search engines does not really care whether the title is "noob needs help with quaternions in three.js" or "quaternion rotation flipped 90° in three.js". after all, the whole page is indexed and the question text will be found

Comment: @clockw0rk Stack Overflow is intended to be a **high-quality** repository of questions and answers. Superfluous slang like "n00b" is entirely contrary to high quality.

Comment: It seems like only a matter of time before ChatGPT reads questions and answers and can create a better title then the best user. In light of this certain re-titling of all content, it doesn't seem very useful to black-list specific words from the title.

Comment: @RobertLongson That's actually hilarious lol

Comment: @IanKemp "High quality" is not a standard metric though. Does that mean "100% stellar" or "at least 75% of the content needs to be good enough"? Dunno. People only keep talking in terms which mean something different to each person.

Comment: @Gimby Are encyclopedias littered with Internet slang that has zero bearing on their content? No. And neither should this site be.

Comment: @zcoop98 _"but "newb" never belongs in a title, full stop."_ I want to make a witty joke about the fact this comment exists in a post with "noob" in the title.

Comment: If we're going to be delicate about words then you should probably not say "blacklist" either

Comment: "Noob" and words like it don't belong in a title. They are words that should belong in the body of a question, where anything not describing the issue (concisely) should be. However, blacklisting the words from titles isn't necessary, and Stack Overflow should just include a warning as stated by @Kevin B considering it could be part of a string concerning the issue.

Comment: I don't have a big issue with people calling themselves noobs but might call it out if it does not add any value to the question, especially in the title. Warning is suitable, rather than trying to catch it with regex/AI/technology. 

What I do have a bigger issue with is the word "blacklist" which carries an ill-desired connotation. Suggest using the work "blocklist" instead.

Comment: I would favor banning it from the title but I would also favor adding a 'noob' tag. This clearly indicates to the community an entry level persons skill, entry level questions that may be highly beneficial to others who are new as well. Part of the issue with being a noob is not knowing how to define something with the proper term and trying their darn best to not butcher the question. Community seeing the 'noob' tag would hopefully give way to people to not bash the heck out of the OP.

Comment: @zcoop98 but it does result in worse titles. People using synonyms, other Unicode characters that look similar, random punctuation, whitespace, or just misspelling the word. They mean you can't search for the problem word anymore, they look bad etc

Comment: @edjm Proposals for [beginner] tags or similar level tags have been discussed to death and ultimately were declined. We want all questions (and answers) to be of similarly high quality, not striated with bands of crap-level questions, middling-level questions, and great questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree that in an ideal world all questions would be of high quality but noobs are noobs and therefore are not usually going to post a high quality question because they are not familiar enough with whatever they are starting on to even know the proper names, terms, ideas behind the topic. Asking a question on something they no nothing of one cannot be like why didn't you just use the 'X' that you knew nothing about or set the 'Y' to a value you did not know existed, or change the 'Z' in this system folder that you never heard of that changes the environment setting you need.

Comment: @IanKemp *"Are encyclopedias littered with Internet slang that has zero bearing on their content? No. And neither should this site be"* - indeed. The unfortunate thing is that people will not now and not ever compare Stack Overflow to an encyclopedia. So the slang will keep coming, no matter what.

Comment: Uncle Stef is not afraid [to use 'noob developers'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coHf24E4aKQ&t=37s).

Comment: Slightly related: *[Simple English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_English_Wikipedia)* - *"... a modified English-language ... primarily in Basic English and Learning English ...  one of seven Wikipedias ... English-based pidgin or creole. ... for people with different needs, such as students, children, adults with learning difficulties, and people who are trying to learn English. ... basic presentation style makes it helpful for beginners learning English. Its simpler word structure and syntax ... can make the information easier to understand"*

Comment: Related on MSE: [Should we edit "Noob" out of titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41860/997587)

Answer (score 64):

I could agree with blacklisting it from titles *if and only if* an accompanying explanation as to why this isn't a good fit for a title followed it.

The challenge there is getting prose written that's simple enough to understand for someone in this mentality that makes it clear as to why this isn't advised.

A lot of people use it as a scapegoat without really realizing that the scapegoat isn't needed here, and there will (more than likely) be a kind of tug-of-war when it comes to the curation/moderation aspect, as one could believe that stating your obvious lacking skill in something would justify a bad question.

Whatever prose we come up with, we have to *avoid* that scenario.

Comment: Some verbiage to pick and choose from: "Please do not try to categorize the difficulty of the material, or your own level of experience, in question titles. As Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, this is not relevant information. Questions that meet standards will be answered at a level appropriate to the question, and answers will be edited for clarity if necessary. Each question may be simple or at an introductory level; but it must be specific, asked clearly and directly, on topic, and not a duplicate. Please see [ask] and the [tour] for details."

Comment: Also consider that some users first language is not English.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel:  I prefer, "Don't worry about your expertise level; all levels of developers are welcome here!" instead.  Concise, to the point, and someone won't immediately scream "tl;dr" like I just did when reading the long prose.

Answer (score 54):

My opinion is that the current experience level of a developer or the perceived state of code never needs to be labelled while posting a minimal, clear, reproducible question or educational answer.

That said, I believe that targeting the keyword "noob" (and its spelling variations) is only calling out a fraction of a whole group of reasonably scrubbed content from posts.

Every post that I've ever encountered that includes self-deprecating terminology would have been just as clear without it.

We should play the long game here.

1. Officially ask users to not include these superfluous remarks while posting content (questions, answers, and comments) via help text.
2. Encourage reviewers and editors to remove irrelevant text.

Removing the noob name-calling from content just goes into the same routine as removing:

- "**Thanks in advance**"
- "**Anyone can suggest a good approach**"
- "**Hi Stack Overflow readers**"
- "**I have been researching for days**"
- "**This is my grandma's code**"
- "**If I need to add more details, just tell me what you need**"
- "**Sorry, I've only been a [language] programmer for 2 days**"
- ... and much, much more.

Whenever posting or editing, simply ask yourself if the text is just as potent with less text -- that should generally guide you to a better result.

Comment: Exactly as I was going to say. Phrases like these are noise that should be removed, even if there's a good question underneath. OP's search, [with a bit of modification](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20newbie), gives a great starting point for editors looking for something to do.

Comment: Editing is certainly a much more productive path to go here, or even a warning as KevinB alludes to in the comments on this main post. Don't go editing out comments about grandma's code though, those are crucial, and indicate to readers that everything is just the way it should be. That code has been in the family for generations.

Comment: and the ubiquitous "I have a doubt". Which isn't just superfluous, but very very bad English.

Comment: @jwenting A lot of users here aren't native English speakers so I don't see the point in calling that out.

Comment: @Soltius it's almost become a meme over the years for homework questions asked by lazy schoolkids.

Comment: Oh OK. Could also stem from a literal translation from OP's original language (eg French).

Comment: @jwenting - As far as I know in Indian English that is more or less synonymous with "I have a question" - so it is just a dialect thing (like "trunk" vs "boot"). See also https://english.stackexchange.com/a/294126/17611

Comment: Regardless, we don't need askers to tell us that "they have a question/doubt". We can figure that out from the fact that they are posting a question.

Comment: @mickmackusa You would think that, and you would thus be doing more thinking than the users who generally post such questions.

Comment: I wonder if "noob question" really does belong in a list of superfluous phrases.  I find myself increasingly adding little markers to indicate the scope of the question.  Eg I sometimes write _"this is not an XY question, I really want to know this"_... and the opposite end of the spectrum I sometimes want to express _"I don't really know what I'm doing here, feel free to re-engineer my solution"_.  To me "noob question" says that so much more succinctly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with inviting contributors to offer completely different approaches versus what you've attempted.  You don't need to put yourself down with some slang term. Intelligently state your concerns and ultimate desired result; subject matter experts will sniff out XY problems.

Comment: I think that may by the trickiest problem of the term. I wouldn't even see it as [self] deprecating though I wouldn't use it to describe others in a public setting. I think it's a term that has wildly different emotional impact depending on the reader.

Comment: @IanKemp my thesis is that typical Internet denizens are **addicted** to discussion forums, and cannot see any site that hosts UGC as anything other than a discussion forum. It's not that they *aren't thinking* about the fact that "I have a question" is superfluous before asking a question; it's that they either *don't care*, or *consider it proper etiquette* to try to get someone's attention before beginning to speak.

Comment: @Soltius The point in calling that out is so that they improve. Simple as that.

Answer (score 26):

Banning words from titles will do little to change the underlying insecurity of the author.

English has many words, inflections and speech patterns which are used to alter the way in which the raw content will be perceived. A classic example is adding "*Well, ...*" to the beginning of an answer which, depending on inflection, may indicate either a patient and respectful response, or an impatient and exasperated retort, to the asker's question.

While these kinds of "interjections" are not desirable in our formal Q&A format, it's an uphill battle to fight back against the perfectly common human desire to couch or shroud our ignorance (which may feel very vulnerable) in protective word salads: preemptive apologizing ("*Sorry, I should know this, but...*"), submissive contextualizing ("*I know this is a noob/student question...*") and relationship building ("*Hi and thanks for reading!*"), just to name a few.

**All that to say...** banning "noob" will just cause authors to **reach for other words** or phrases to communicate their discomfort and attempt to shield themselves from group shaming. We already encourage new users to avoid this kind of "noise", and as they gain experience and confidence it will hopefully feel less necessary. In the meantime, it's not hard for higher rep users to edit this content out.

Given how little is gained and the annoyance some will feel when writing legitimate questions, I think it'd be best to avoid this particular feature request. For example: you would not have been able to write your question title as-is with such a filter in place.

It's not hard to imagine fairly legit titles that would include such a common word:

- **How can I filter out words like "noob" from this list?**
- **My console output doesn't match this "From Noob to Pro" tutorial**
- **How can I replace politician's name with "noob" in this gag browser plugin?**

**Data suggests "noob" alone isn't currently a significant problem**

The hard numbers would also suggest that, while it might be irritating to see in a title, the problem is really not that widespread.

As of January, 2023, there are about [350 questions with "noob" in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+title%3Anoob+score%3A1+closed%3Ano) with a score of 1 or higher, that aren't closed, dating back across the past 14 years. Assuming the score and close-state indicate a sufficiently-high quality question that required no other editing, then that means that this proposal would save us the effort of editing about 2 questions per month, on average.

There may have been many more that originally included "noob" but were subsequently edited. In that case: the system seems to be working just fine. Questions with zero or less score or that have been closed clearly had other issues already, where removing a single word from the title would not have saved them.

**What's the justification for "noob" over "beginner", "student" or more controversial words?**

In my opinion, banning this one non-offensive word is not going to save editors any time, and will lead to a bunch of other requests to ban similarly informal but innocuous words, which would naturally lead to the question: if we are banning words which are not controversial, what about all the controversial words we allow, like "blacklist"?

**In summary:**

- If you ban "noob", then users will just say "student", "beginner", "newbie", etc, which hasn't saved anybody any work
- I'd argue it's rare that a question with "noob" in the title will have no other issues that must be addressed. Banning this one word will, in my opinion, not reduce a significant amount of work for editors
- "Noob" is an informal, silly word that can nevertheless be used appropriately in a question title. It is not inherently offensive to any group of users, unlike certain other words (like "***blacklist***")

Comment: `Given how little is gained and the annoyance some will feel when writing legitimate questions, I think it'd be best to avoid this particular feature request.` Unfortunately we as curators are placed in a position where we have to choose the lesser of two evils: preventing the asking of some questions that are perfectly on-topic for this site, or actually having enough capacity to curate the site enough to prevent it from turning into a completely useless cesspool. Sorry, but I'll take option two.

Comment: The example question titles you gave are pretty contrived and easily rephrased without the word.

Comment: `How to generate all the palindrome variations of "noob"?`

Comment: ‘How can I filter out a specific word from a list?’, ‘Having trouble with a tutorial for beginners on FrameworkJS’ and ‘How can I replace text on a webpage with something else in this gag browser plugin?’ would be much better titles, and I have a hard time believing someone would choose ‘noob’ of all things as an example in the first place. Banning ‘problem’ was much more, well, problematic, because that word constitutes a part of a number of terms of art (‘halting problem’, ‘three-body problem’), where it isn’t easily replaced by a synonym or omitted. This doesn’t remotely apply to ‘noob’.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, ‘Having trouble with a tutorial for beginners on FrameworkJS’ is still an awful title, because it doesn’t explain what the trouble *was*.

Comment: (i) Someone who has looked at their `/etc/passwd` closely might have even guessed what I meant without reading the full question. At least I didn’t title it ‘Mystery entries, what could they be for?!?!/1’. So I don’t know what kind of ‘gotcha’ it was supposed to be. (ii) Given that the ‘noob tutorial’ and ‘FrameworkJS’ don’t actually exist, this is just an unconvincing hypothetical, contrived to trigger a false positive. (iii) A good title would have mentioned at least a single specific symptom: blank page, errors in the console, whatever it may be. Spare me the ‘trouble’: it’s content-free.

Comment: @user3840170 I think this conversation spun out of control a bit. Apologies for any offense. I take your criticism: I could have spent more time crafting better sample questions. I still stand by my points.

Comment: The fact that there are unclosed questions with any concerning attribute just indicates that they have not been edited/curated, not that the concerning attribute is by any means "ok". We see the same excuse being used for off-topic questions; "there's a tag for it tho". "this question from a decade ago isn't closed, why is mine?" 350 questions is barely a rounding error with the number of questions on SO.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I'm confused by your comment. Are you echoing my point, or are you making a counter argument? I agree with everything you've said and I don't see how my post says anything otherwise.

Comment: I'm countering the assertion that "noob" isn't a problem because there are questions that have that content in them that aren't closed (basically the paragraph "Data suggests "noob" isn't currently a problem"). It's not a problem now, but how much of that is due to alert curators editing out the word? Are we trivializing a problem because of how much unseen work is being done? I agree that bans are a blunt instrument, but it's the tool we're given.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I never said it isn't a problem. However, I'd argue it's a trivial problem. By my reckoning, over the past 14 years, there are only 350 questions using that word in the title that have survived rounds of editing, voting and/or closure. How many "noob" questions are perfectly fine except for that one word? I'd argue very few. Seems like a lot of work for very little reward. You could even argue that "noob" is an effective flag for a post in need of other edits. Regardless, seems like a bad precedent with no clear reason behind it. Why "noob" and not "beginner" or "student"?

Comment: Ok... actually, I kind of did say it isn't a problem... I could have said that differently.

Comment: *"Banning words from titles will do little to change the underlying insecurity of the author."* - very, very true, but it is a signal that they would otherwise not receive. People need to get triggers to know they're on the path of doing something ill-advised. Whether they choose to acknowledge them is not something that can be guaranteed, but at least it cannot be said that the site leaves you stumbling in the dark.

Comment: @Gimby - I perfectly agree with that. If the proposal was something more like "show a warning" then I'd be in favor of it. That's feedback that the author can choose to use not just with their title, but the entire question content. However, outright banning a word is a bit too extreme in my opinion. _Banning_ should be reserved for straight-up, clear-cut, widely-agreed-upon abusive language. Words that don't fall in that category should be allowed, even if it means that editing is occasionally needed.

Answer (score 23):

I'm not entirely sure how the blocking mechanism works exactly, but I just wanted to add that we should be careful with "auto-blocking" `noob`, `noobs` and variations of it.
In very rare cases it could actually be part of the question (e.g. involving [New Out Of Box Software (noobs)](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs), [noobaa](https://github.com/noobaa), etc)

Comment: Because of this reason is why I would favour mickmackusa's answer. Encouraging people to edit out noise is something that needs to be done more

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Prevention is better than cure. The fewer noisy questions posted here, the fewer that need to be edited. As an asker it is ultimately **your** responsibility to ensure your question is as easily answerable as possible, not our responsibility as curators to panel-beat it into an answerable form.

Comment: @IanKemp but as NullDev as rightly pointed out, "noob" is an anacronym that shouldn't be prevented from being entered. Yes it is a fairly niche anacronym to use, but people using the anacronym correctly should not be punished

Comment: I think one way to improve titles blocking mechanism is to implement an advanced NLP ( natural language processing ) that provides a score of correctness, if you want to ban specific words, there will always be a way to get away with it, for example : noob can be altered to n0ob or nooob or noobie, also, **i have a problem**, which is irrelevant and can also be altered to other words like prob / problam ... ( I have actually seen these stuff around on SO ).

Answer (score 7):

In favor. Stating that someone is a noob/beginner doesn't add anything valuable to a question. I almost always remove introductions like "I recently started..." and the likes too.

Also, someone experienced might ask a beginner question.

Comment: Otherwise, you could use the word "Beginner" itself

Comment: ‘Beginner’ is equally useless, especially in a title. Look at <https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/>: it’s a pretty basic question, highly upvoted, and it contains none of that nonsense.

Answer (score -18):

Add an AI [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) model which classifies title content as "self-deprecating", and other requirements as necessary. Notify the user via a popup:

- "Using X does not add any extra value to the question content. You may want to consider rephrasing X or omitting X,Y."

I am surprised to see so much critique against AI/[ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning). FYI, it's implementable in weeks rather months and won't cost more than estimated $500/month for cloud GPU-accelerated instances deployed globally. Considering the write only traffic.

Comment: For now (and I hope never), Stack Overflow isn't going to be using OpenAPI.  There's already regexes in place to detect this, and while they're not *the greatest*, I'd rather that over AI.

Comment: @Makoto regex cant handle every case, thats when machine learning comes into picture.

Comment: I'd conjecture that "good enough" would be enough here.  Besides, the fact that people add this is a social construct, not a technological one.  I only weakly support the filter because I know that people have a need to maintain face and want to speak at liberty about their problem, knowing that to Some Expert Somewhere™ their problem is trivial or insignificant.  *How* we block it is highly orthogonal to this discussion.  *That* we block it is only part one of a many-part mindset shift for askers in this position.

Comment: @Makoto LOL what's up with the hate towards AI?

Comment: @nikhilswami Eh, no. AI also has a certain error rate. Any automated system written today has errors. The major difference between regex and AI is that one is trivially computable, while the other would require a significant investment in AI-accelerator compute hardware to keep up with asking volumes. ML will not handle everything, and neither will regex. But one has a significantly lower resource requirement, while still being good enough or even on-par with regex. The major keyword here shouldn't be to deal with 100% of content. Even 90-95% is a significant reduction in manual labour

Comment: and that is generally the goal with automation. We're not at a point where machines can fully take the place of humans for gruntwork (unfortunately), but taking out as much as possible with as little cost as possible, and through that reducing the amount of gruntwork required by the far too few overworked and undertooled curators allows for far more efficient moderation of all content, even if the automation step doesn't actually cover everything

Comment: @WalterMonecke:  Because there's no point to it in this case.  It's not a broad tool to just be applied *wherever*; there is a suitable time and place to use it, and this is very much neither.

Comment: @Makoto pretty sure any AI would perform than any regex.

Comment: @WalterMonecke:  You're missing the forest for the trees.  Blocking the text in the title is literally the beginning.  How it's done is really not consequential.  Regex is *just fine* for this.  The second, harder part that this answerer is missing is that this social construct does have some high hurdles to it that I elaborate in an earlier comment.  Don't just force AI through as a "solution" when you're not considering the actual problem.

Comment: Ah sorry @Makoto I was speaking in general terms when comparing AI vs regex. I understand your point.

Answer (score -21):

I think the term 'noob' is pretty well understood as a cheery and slightly self deprecating way of admitting to be a beginner.  I don't mind it.

Comment: `noob` doesn't usually belong in a title, since titles are usually reserved for info concerning the issue, not the person who has it.

Comment: On this site the information about the OP is irrelevant on questions. Whatever the OP want to share about themselves could included in their bio. Fun fact: There are a lot of users named "noob"

Comment: Nobody searches the site for "hey guys I'm a noob how to convert a string to an integer thanks in advance", they search for "How to convert a string to an integer". The reason to not ban "noob" is that it sometimes appears in legitimate technical contexts. We don't need conversational noise in question titles. I'm afraid to look but there's probably a "thanks in advance" testing library for Ruby or something preventing us from banning that too...